# Google Sheets: Change text color of multiple cells if checkbox is checked?

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

I have set up my conditional formatting to change text colors of a range of cells if a checkbox in that row has been checked.

However, this only changes text color of one of the cells.

Can anyone tell me why and has a solution to this?

**Video:**

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_G0I13o7CzdLFYc4Zwqg6-9M0lFkReV6/view?usp=drivesdk

**Demo sheet:**

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/19vIBglfyRxKh5TTqva7ZD6-7dJRt5xoXrNTFYFdJjFo/edit#gid=1913565402

**Screenshot:**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this [conditional formatting](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/78413) custom formula rule for the range `B2:D`:

```
=$E2
```

See [GimelG's explanation](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/91546414?msgid=91591478) and [Lance's explanation](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/60050658?msgid=60238341) of how absolute and relative addresses work in a conditional formatting custom formula rule.